# org.apache.hadoop.hbase.NotServingRegionException: Region is not online: -ROOT-,,0 what is the reason behind for this error

Tags: hadoop, hbase

Thanks for taking interesting in my Question :) when ever i fire query like scan,put, create for any table in hbase shell  am getting  following error. and hbase shell  gives the result listing of tables and description of tables .... so would you please help me to clear out of this ? 
And also can u please tell me the meaning of the structure **-ROOT-,,0**

About versions am using

**HBase 0.92.1-cdh4.1.2
Hadoop 2.0.0-cdh4.1.2**

***ERROR: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.NotServingRegionException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.NotServingRegionException: Region is not online: -ROOT-,,0***

Comment: Ah..Classic error..This is a configuration issue..You have not configured hbase properly

Comment: Thanx debarshi :) for your  quick response , earlier hbase working fine in the sense i loaded bulk data and scan the data from tables too ... suddenly it started throwing exception  while am trying to fetch the data from tables. And about configuration i haven't changed much configuration in hadoop , so can u please suggest me in which config file we can change the properties to get out of this error ??? Thank you once again for ur help  :) :)

Comment: Can you inspect or past the log files?

Comment: Hey debarhsi :) am giving **bold hbase-Region **  server logs, where my server name is madhu-centos .  I have the following questions                     1) can u please  tell me the exact file where i needs to change properties  with what ? 2)If i want to change the hbase storing directory , where i needs to give the new path ?                    i read from different articles on net , as this error was not shwing after they formatted all the tables in the storage ... is it true ? i am ready to do that one also if it's the final option .. please suggest me ... Thanks again for ur help :)

Comment: How your problem was fixed? Second I have about 300Gb data in hbase and I want to take it its backup in external storage so that in future I can upload it if system crash. how I can do backup and then upload to hbase.

Comment: So is there a confirmed answer here? I'm faced with the exactly same issue. please help.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error. Zookeeper was handled by HBase.
(It wasn't standalone!)

So a quick fix is:

```
$ hbase zkcli
zookeeper_cli> rmr /hbase/root-region-server
```

Comment: Badly written answer, it actually deletes the node.

Comment: so, what's the final working solution to this? any definitive guide please? Thanks!

Comment: Somehow for my cluster, I didn't have root-region-server, so instead, I deleted `rmr /hbase/meta-region-server`, when I retried, I'm still faced with the same situation.

Comment: Hey I am also facing the same issue. I tried above method but when I ls the /hbase there is no root-region-server. any suggestions? please?

Answer (score 1):

By clearing the zookeeper nodes hbase started  working fine :) what exactly i followed was        (it is not recommended and you should have your
HBase and ZK shut down first):

```
### shut down ZM and HBase 
1) for each ZK node:
su                          // login as root

cd $ZOOKEEPER_HOME       

cp data/myid myid           // backup existing myid file to ZooKeeper's home folder

rm data/* -Rf

rm dadalog/* -Rf

mkdir -p data

mkdir -p datalog

cp myid data/myid           // restore the myid backup so no need to recreate myid again

2) for each ZK node:
(start ZK )

3) finally 
(start HBase)
```

By clearing data and datalog, you should have a very clean ZooKeeper. 
Hope these help and good luck.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
My Error was ERROR: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.NotServingRegionException: Region ROLE,,1457743249518.221f6f7fdacacbe179674267f8d06575. is not online on ddtmwutelc3ml01.azure-dev.us164.corpintra.net,16020,1459486618702
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.getRegionByEncodedName(HRegionServer.java:2898)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.getRegion(RSRpcServices.java:947)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.scan(RSRpcServices.java:2235)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.ClientProtos$ClientService$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientProtos.java:32205)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcServer.call(RpcServer.java:2114)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.CallRunner.run(CallRunner.java:101)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor.consumerLoop(RpcExecutor.java:130)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor$1.run(RpcExecutor.java:107)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

**Resolution is :**

run below command

```
$ hbase zkcli
zookeeper_cli> rmr /hbase/root-region-server
```

then

Stop hbase and zk
backup mydir from cd /hadoop/zookeeper
deleter everything from cd /hadoop/zookeeper
restart zookeeper then hbase