# Hbase NotServingRegionException: Region is not online

Tags: hbase

One of my Hbase regionservers went offline because of HDFS going into Safe Mode -- or couldn't come back online because of Safe Mode (chicken-egg issue) -- so I fixed this and got the region server working again, but then I could no longer query Hbase.  I received an error, `NotServingRegionException: Region is not online: <my table>...`

Another [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14145846/org-apache-hadoop-hbase-notservingregionexception-region-is-not-online-root) and similar [blog post](http://architects.dzone.com/articles/hbase-error-region-not-online) suggested deleting some entries from Zookeeper, but this sounded like a potentially dangerous route to go, especially since our error messages didn't match.

What is a safe solution to this issue?

Comment: Are you using separate zookeeper? Or HBase's one? The problem takes place when HBase handles zookeeper itself and of course deleting zookeeper entries solves the issue.

Comment: I'm using separate zookeeper servers.  Correct me if I'm wrong, but won't deleting zookeeper entries cause data loss? My understanding is that zookeeper keeps track of where table entries are stored, so deleting any of the zookeeper data would lose track of where the entries are.

Comment: No. Zookeeper takes care of your nodes to be up and healthy and if a node goes down tries to restart it or if the node which went down was master replace it with another one. So no data loss will happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution that worked for me was to simply restart Hbase Master.

(On Ubuntu w CDH4): `sudo service hbase-master restart`

Answer (score 2):

On Azure HBase I needed to run the following:

```
hbase master stop
hbase master start
```